# Does Mountain Lion remove headers in /usr/include?

Tags: macos

Is it just me or common to everybody that all the header files that was in the /usr/include is no longer there?

Which is causing boost bootstrap to fail with this error:

```
### Using 'darwin' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
cc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c function.c glob.c hash.c  hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c pwd.c class.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c
In file included from command.c:17:
./jam.h:317:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
#include <sys/types.h>
     ^
1 error generated.[/code]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have stuff in there on my Mountain Lion install (upgraded from Lion, however)

```
Macbook Pro:~> find /usr/include/ | wc -l
    2820
Macbook Pro:~> ls -l /usr/include/sys/types.h 
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  10133 28 Jul 04:14 /usr/include/sys/types.h
```

Comment: hmm... that's really weird. 3 of my computer installed with Mountain Lion doesn't have headers in the /usr/include

Comment: I also have XCode + commandline tools, perhaps that put them there?

Comment: hmm... That's weird. I got Xcode Commandline as well. oh well, looks like it's just me. I'll figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This also happened to me, upgrading to Mountain Lion removed commandline tools. I just needed to go to Xcode and install again. Solved.

Comment: do you have header files in /usr/include/ before installing the commandline tools?

Comment: @NegativeZero No, it was empty or there wasn't one, I'm not sure whether I've mkdir an empty one to try to remediate and later noticed that I just needed to install the commandline tools.

Comment: arh, it looks like someone had the similar issue with me then.